# Angular Material - Table Pagination in Mat-Tab Group Not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-pagination-example-mvdhhw

Need Help. Im trying to use Table pagination in mat-tab group. From a single table fetching two different records "Concrete" and "Cotton".

Populating those records in two mat-tabs. In First tab ("Concrete") pagination is working and in second tab ("Cotton") initial loading was correct but pagination was not working.

I'll be glad for any help. Thanks in advance :)

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { catchError, map, startWith, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-mat-table',
  templateUrl: './simple-mat-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simple-mat-table.component.scss'],
})
export class SimpleMatTableComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: any = MatPaginator;
  title = 'angular-material-app';
  displayColumns = ['id', 'name', 'material'];
  totalData: any;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  pageSizes = [3, 5, 7];
  outData: any;
  material: string = 'Concrete';

  getList(material: string, page: number, pageSize: number) {
    const url = new URL('https://64faa3decb9c00518f7a0e89.mockapi.io/product');
    url.searchParams.append('material', material);
    url.searchParams.append('page', page.toString());
    url.searchParams.append('limit', pageSize.toString());
    return this.http.get(url.toString());
  }

  getTotal(material: string) {
    const url = new URL('https://64faa3decb9c00518f7a0e89.mockapi.io/product');
    url.searchParams.append('material', material);
    this.http.get(url.toString()).subscribe((data) => {
      this.outData = data;
      return (this.totalData = this.outData.length);
    });
  }

  onTabChange($event: { index: number }) {
    if ($event.index === 0) {
      this.material = 'Concrete';
      this.totalData = this.getTotal(this.material);
    } else {
      this.material = 'Cotton';
      this.totalData = this.getTotal(this.material);
    }
    this.ngAfterViewInit();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit');
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.getTotal(this.material);
    console.log(this.totalData);
    this.paginator.page
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.getList(
            this.material,
            this.paginator.pageIndex + 1,
            this.paginator.pageSize
          ).pipe(catchError(() => observableOf(null)));
        }),
        map((data) => {
          return data;
        })
      )
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      });
  }
}
function observableOf(arg0: null): any {
  throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
}
```

```html
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Concrete">
    <div class="aterimal-datatables" style="overflow-x: auto;">
      <mat-table
        id="matTable"
        [dataSource]="dataSource"
        matSort
        class="mat-elevation-z8"
      >
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            id
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.id }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            Name
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.name }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="material">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            Material
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.material }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row
          *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns; sticky: true"
        ></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
      <mat-paginator
        #paginator
        showFirstLastButtons
        [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizes"
        [length]="totalData"
      >
        <!--(page)="onPaginateChange($event)"-->
      </mat-paginator>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Cotton">
    <div class="aterimal-datatables" style="overflow-x: auto;">
      <mat-table
        id="matTable"
        [dataSource]="dataSource"
        matSort
        class="mat-elevation-z8"
      >
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            id
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.id }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            Name
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.name }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="material">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            Material
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.material }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row
          *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns; sticky: true"
        ></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
      <mat-paginator
        #paginator
        showFirstLastButtons
        [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizes"
        [length]="totalData"
      >
        <!--(page)="onPaginateChange($event)"-->
      </mat-paginator>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

You are using two paginators for two tables.

From this code,

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: any = MatPaginator;
```

This will get the first `MatPaginator` element, thus the paginator for the second tab will not work correctly.

---

**Solution: Use only 1 paginator**

1. Remove all the `<matpaginator` elements after `<mat-table>`. You should use only 1 `<mat-paginator>` by placing it to the bottom of the page.

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Concrete">
    <div class="aterimal-datatables" style="overflow-x: auto;">
      <mat-table
        id="matTable"
        [dataSource]="dataSource"
        matSort
        class="mat-elevation-z8"
      >
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            id
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.id }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            Name
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.name }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="material">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            Material
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.material }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row
          *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns; sticky: true"
        ></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Cotton">
    <div class="aterimal-datatables" style="overflow-x: auto;">
      <mat-table
        id="matTable"
        [dataSource]="dataSource"
        matSort
        class="mat-elevation-z8"
      >
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            id
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.id }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            Name
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.name }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="material">
          <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
            Material
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.material }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row
          *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns; sticky: true"
        ></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<mat-paginator
  #paginator
  showFirstLastButtons
  [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizes"
  [length]="totalData"
>
</mat-paginator>
```

2. While changing the tab, you should reset the page to the first page to avoid showing incorrect items for the selected page.

```
onTabChange($event: { index: number }) {
  if ($event.index === 0) {
    this.material = 'Concrete';
    this.getTotal(this.material);
  } else {
    this.material = 'Cotton';
    this.getTotal(this.material);
  }

  this.paginator.firstPage();
  this.ngAfterViewInit();
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-pagination-example-t6jkhh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsimple-mat-table%2Fsimple-mat-table.component.ts)

---

From my perspective, both tables and paginators duplicate, moving the `<mat-table>` and `<mat-paginator>` out from the `<mat-tab>` and create only 1 `<mat-table>` and `<mat-paginator>` after the `<mat-tab-group>` element will resolve the issue.

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Concrete">
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Cotton">
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<div class="aterimal-datatables" style="overflow-x: auto;">
  <mat-table
    id="matTable"
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    matSort
    class="mat-elevation-z8"
  >
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        id
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.id }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        Name
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.name }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="material">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        Material
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"> {{ order.material }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row
      *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns; sticky: true"
    ></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  <mat-paginator
    #paginator
    showFirstLastButtons
    [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizes"
    [length]="totalData"
  >
    <!--(page)="onPaginateChange($event)"-->
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

[Demo 2 @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-pagination-example-cswjx9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsimple-mat-table%2Fsimple-mat-table.component.ts)